# Watson Knowledge Studio account subscription

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-knowledge-studio

I have created WKS model in lite version of IBM Cloud.
I want to understand,if i will upgrade my account then can I reuse my model with paid subscription?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

as I read the following document, you can upgrade Watson Knowledge Studio from Lite plan to paid plan (Standard, Premium) without any data losing including the machine learning model you created.
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/watson-knowledge-studio/upgrade.html#upgrade